# What would be proper grammar for stating a person has worked on projects ranging from three different subjects?

Tags: prepositions

For example,

> I worked on projects ranging from information technology to human resources to manufacturing.

Is using "to" twice at the end of that statement grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically the construct "**ranging from ... to ... to ...** " is perfectly fine.  Whether it *makes sense* to use that form, needs to be considered too.

You can use this form if you think that there is a *natural progression* from one subject to the next ***and*** from the next to the third.  This is *most acceptable* and even recommended if they all in adjacent or related fields, like "research", "design", "manufacturing".

This is pretty much a personal preference, but I find the three fields you named, "*information technology*", "*human resources*", "*manufacturing*", virtually *unrelated*.

Of course it depends on what exactly your projects constituted, what it was that you **did** in each of them.  For instance, one could work on *data visualization algorithms*, then it really doesn't matter what field you're in.  It might matter a bit ***if*** the application domain knowledge is required, but if specifics are supplied by somebody else, then it hardly matters altogether.

All in all, such expressions like "*from field**1** to field**2** to field**3***" are often treated as *buzzwords* or *professional jargon*, and you need to treat them as such.

Comment: ranging from x to y **and** Z.

Answer (score 0):

Victor's explanation is thorough. I might add in situations where the subjects appear unrelated, use the following modifier:

**I worked on an array of projects ranging from information technology to human relations to manufacturing.**

This is common in resumes for mid- to upper-level management to show a general knowledge of a start-to-finish project on consignment, like a government grant.